# How can I explain the pointer of an array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, pointers, dereference

Consider:

```
void print_array(int(*p)[10], int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", (*p)[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[10] = { 0 };
    int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    int(*p)[10] = arr;

    print_array(p, len);
    return 0;
}
```

Why can the code of the *print_array* function print the information of the array?

I didn't realized the code, `(*p)[i]`, so I want the master of programmer can help me to work out this question.

I guess that the reason that I didn't understand this code is that I don't realize the knowledge of the pointer of array.

Comment: Read the [C-FAQ Pointers & Arrays section](https://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html) and possibly other sections.  And there are a zillion other online sources that explain this well.  First study yourself, then come back with detailed questions.

Comment: Note: `int(*p)[10] = arr;` is wrong. It should be `int(*p)[10] = &arr;`. You could skip `p` and call `print_array` directly though: `print_array(&arr, len);`

Comment: Start by ensuring that you have written valid C then worry about what it does once you have gotten that far. [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start from this line

```
int(*p)[10] = arr;
```

The array `arr` used as an initializer is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element of the type `int *`.

However the initialized pointer `p` has the type `int ( * )[10]` and there is no implicit conversion between these two pointers.

So the compiler should issue at least a warning.

You have to write

```
int(*p)[10] = &arr;
```

On the other hand, values of the expressions `arr` and `&arr` are equal each other. It is the initial address of the extent of memory occupied by the array. (The address of the first element of an array is equal to the address of the array as a whole object).

So the function accepts a pointer of the type `int ( * )[10]` that points to an array.

Dereferencing the pointer in the expression `(*p)` you get an object of the type `int[10]` (the array pointed to by the pointer) that is an object of the array type.

So you can apply the subscript operator `(*p)[i]` to access elements of the array.

Answer (score 0):

`p` is a pointer to the 10 elements `int` array.

`(*p)[i]` first, you dereference the pointer `p` and you get the array of 10 integers. Then you access the `i`th element of the array.

Answer (score -2):

An array is a contiguous memory allocation, hence the statement `int(*p)[10] = arr;`, creating an array of pointers where p[0] is pointing to the first element of the array.

Now at the function call, *p[i] leads *(p + i). It keeps on incrementing, hence it will keep on printing the array elements 1st, 2nd, 3rd and so on.

Comment: `*p[i]` leads `*(p + i)` - yes, but anything but `p[0]` is pointing outside the array so _"... will keep on printing the array elements 1st, 2nd, 3rd and so on"_ is wrong. `(*p)[i]` would do the correct thing though.